# Multi-coring in SimGrid

Tags: c, simgrid

In platform file there is parameter such as `core`:

```
<host id="Jupiter" speed="76.296Mf" core="2"/>
```

But this parameter doesn't affect the time of task executing.
How it should be done that time of executing will give different values depending on number of cores in the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this parameter allows two tasks to run concurrently on the host. So, one task cannot be multithreaded in SimGrid and you need 2 of them to take advantage of a multi-core host.

Note that I'm not completely sure that this area is perfectly bug free...